# Is there a transcript of Uhura's conversation with the Klingons?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, star-trek-into-darkness, klingon-language

In *Star Trek Into Darkness*, there is a scene on Kronos where Uhura leaves the shuttle to converse with the Klingons. What was the conversation about? Is there a transcript?

Comment: I haven't seen it since it was in the theatre, but I'm 90% certain that scene was subtitled...

Comment: @Brandorf My copy did not have any subs. 100% certain :)

Comment: @coleopterist I saw it in theatres and also think I remember subs...

Comment: This can't be found in subtitle file.. actually, its hardwired to the movie picture. I don't know how it wasn't in your copy..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> **Uhura:** "I am here to help you. With Respect. There is a criminal hiding in these ruins. He has killed many of our people."
>
> **Klingon:** "Why should I care about a human killing humans?"
>
> **Uhura:** "Because you care about honor. And this man has none. You and your people are in danger."

(From the subtitles.)

Comment: When I saw it, it read: “ *Uhura:* This is the one damn thing I have to do in this movie except worry about Spock. We can travel faster than light, but we still can’t pass the Bechdel test. *Klingon:* ...? *Uhura:* Whatever. Just grab me by the throat so the boys can start shooting.”

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: You seem to forget that she also saved his bacon later in the movie.

Comment: @Stephan: I have no memory of that. Is it during Spock's fight with Khan on earth?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: That's right. Uhura beams down and stuns Khan just as he's about to crush Spock's skull.

Comment: @Stephan: well, that’s something.

Comment: "well, that’s something." And to quote MST3K, "Of course, you could say that about *anything*."

Answer (score 8):

You can see a copy of the transcript, along with the English and German translations, at [this link](https://plus.google.com/110116202842822234244/posts/Hgh7uuiBBbc).

The link is to a Google+ post containing a scan of the transcript which was released by Marc Okrand (the creator of the Klingon language) through the annual **qepHom** (a meeting of Klingon speakers) in Germany. The scan also includes an explanation of the new vocabulary used in the dialogue. It’s as official as it gets.

From the link above:

> **Uhura:**
>   `jIvuylaH. jIve’. jIyI’. ghach jIvvo’ naH. DaH pIghvamDaq So’’eghtaH. ’ej Dojmey wID - vInDa’ma’ peq.`
>   I am here to help you. With respect. There is a criminal hiding in these ruins. He has killed many of our people.
>
> **Klingon:**
>   `toH, Hey Humanpu’. qatlh DISaH?`
>   Why should I care about a human killing humans?
>
> **Uhura:**
>   `potlhmo’ batlh, vIqawba’. ’ej chIvo’ neH chIw vum’e’. Qob lIb bam SoH chuDlI’ je.`
>   Because you care about honor. And this man has none. You and your people are in danger.

Comment: You should avoid posting answers that are just links. Also, you might want to indicate where the link takes you and whether it's authoritative (or just someone's fansite)

Comment: Okay, I've edited my post to state that it comes from the creator of the language.

Comment: I added the transcript from the link. I thought about formatting the Klingon text in bold, rather than the fixed-width font, but it was hard to see the difference between `I` and `l`.